# Grails transactionManager exception on Run

Tags: spring, grails, netbeans

When compiling a `grails v2.3.3` project I'm getting the following error when running the project in `Netbeans 7.4`:

```
| Loading Grails 2.3.3
| Configuring classpath
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development
| Environment set to development.
| Environment set to development..
| Environment set to development...
| Environment set to development....
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application
| Packaging Grails application.
| Packaging Grails application..
| Packaging Grails application...
| Packaging Grails application....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Running Grails application
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/Iceberg
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
| Error 2013-11-25 14:52:27,036 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by IllegalAccessException: Class org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor can not access a member of class org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator with modifiers "public static"
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

What could possibly cause this? I've searched through StackOverflow but have yet to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it's still broken for _45 JDK in Linux.

The solution in http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10312 worked for me.
Just download the http://www.oleastre.be/export/springloaded-1.1.3.jar, change it in your grails directory (lib/org.springsource.springloaded/springloaded-core/jars) and clean your project.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running:(terminal: java -version)

java version "1.7.0_25"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.12) (7u25-2.3.12-4ubuntu3)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

I had the same problems, this fixed mine:

Download the newest version of Java JDK from Oracle (_45).

Unpack the tar.gz

Change the path in .bashrc (home directory) to match the new bin you downloaded. (the path for grails_home)

Now Grails will use this java version.